# Replace All Occurrences Of a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, replace

I have a string as follows

```
var company = "Microst+Apple+Google";
```

And I want replace all the + signs with %2B

But when I use this code. It returns 0

```
var company = company.replace(/+/g, "%2B");
```

I think JavaScript thinks that + is an arithmetic operation. Is there a special symbol to be used? or can user a variable except directly using the + sign?
If so please mention. Any Idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need escape it :

`var company = company.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");`

It is because `+` is special symbol used to indicate that preceding character should match 1 or more times.

You can read more about regular expressions syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Maybe you want to explain why?

Answer (score 1):

No, JavaScript doesn't think it's an arithmetic operation but + is a quantifier in regular expressions and the regular expression parser doesn't understand yours.

You must escape the `+` :

```
var company = company.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
```

Comment: Does this take the mathod to replace " symbol ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
var company = company.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
```

Or an easier way :

```
var company = encodeURIComponent(company);
```

which will do the same operation as the regex one. Also, it encodes all URI chars like `&`, `"` (quotes), `%` etc... if there is one like it in the string given.

In both cases, the output is :

> Microst%2BApple%2BGoogle